# Mandrill: Unable to send mail through the form

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, forms, mandrill

I have an HTML contact form and I am trying to utilize the Mandrill API for sending email. The form only sends emails to me if I fill out the email section of the form with my email. However if I type something like "example@gmail.com" it will not send to my gmail account.

What am I doing wrong??? Been stuck on this all day.

Here is my html form:

```
<!-- Form Name -->

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your full name here" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address here" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="msg">Message</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">                     
    <textarea class="form-control" id="msg" name="msg" cols="6" rows="6"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formmethod="POST">Send Message</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

here is my contact.js

```
jQuery(function($)  
{
    $("#contact_form").submit(function()
    {
        var email = $("#email").val(); // get email field value
        var name = $("#name").val(); // get name field value
        var msg = $("#msg").val(); // get message field value
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
            data: {
                'key': 'API Key',
                'message': {
                    'from_email': email,
                    'from_name': name,

                    'subject': 'Website Contact Form',
                    'text': msg,
                    'to': [
                    {
                        'email': 'myaddress@gmail.com',
                        'name': 'Taimur K Naziri',
                        'type': 'to'
                    }]
                }
            }
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            alert('Your message has been sent. Thank you!'); // show success message
            $("#name").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
            $("#email").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
            $("#msg").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
        })
        .fail(function(response) {
            alert('Error sending message.');
        });
        return false; // prevent page refresh
    });
});
```

Comment: To clarify: are you saying that this code works for _some_ values you enter into the form (your email), but not for others (gmail email address)?

Comment: it works if i enter my email(gmail address) however it does not work if i enter another person's email(gmail or yahoo address). So if i enter any name with my email the message will be send to me. Oppose to a user inputting their name, their email and their message which should be sent to my gmail. Which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: How does it fail? Do you get an error back from the Mandrill API? Or does the API call succeed, and then something else happens?

Comment: It's working, it just does not work with emails from a yahoo, address, do you happen to know why?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if this could be a Mandrill restrictions.
You should probably use the reply-to header instead of altering the from address.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine, however it does not work when form submitted with an @yahoo.com email address. Haven't figured out why however.

Comment: This is because Yahoo, AOL and Zendesk are rejecting emails being sent from their email addresses that do not originate from their own server. In technical terms they set their dmarc policy to p=reject